# How do I get all rows from dataGrid that have a combobox checked

Tags: wpf, checkbox, datagrid

```
 <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <CheckBox Name="CheckALL" />
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Name="chkDiscontinue" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=CheckALL, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I can click the header check-box and make all check-boxes selected, But Here, I need to Get all selected grids bind to 'IsChecked'

Comment: can you explain what you are looking for here ?

Comment: I need to know, Which all rows in the datagrid i have selected (Checked in checkbox)?

Comment: whats you itemssource ?

Comment: Sorry, I just pasted a part of code for reference.  <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="116" Width="885"
                CanUserAddRows='False'  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=OrderHeader, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding AllOrderHeader}">

Answer (score 1):

Well in datacontext of this view you can get desired by doing this --

```
Your_Item_Source.Where(p=>p.Checked)
```

---

In your OrderHeader class, create a property

```
public bool IsSelected {get;set;} // with inotify please
```

then bind your combobox chkDiscontinue to

```
{Binding IsSelected}
```

Bind your Header checkbox to ViewModel Property

```
public bool SelectAll {get;set;} // with inotify please
```

In setter of this property, set all OrderHeader.IsSelected = value in AllOrderHeader, and in getter your can return status of items in the AllHeaders

Comment: here when i am clicking checkbox , the property 'IsChecked' is not getting notified. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Muds said, if you want bind IsChecked to SelectAll, you should use something like that :

```
Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path= DataContext.SelectAll}
```

Sorry for not posting as reply but I dont have enough points :)

Comment: no wrries we all have had this pain at some time .. you will be thru